# Regex mask last 4 numbers

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
R.replace(/[0-9](?!([0-9]{4}))/g,'*','123456789'); 
yields 12345****

want to input 123-45-6789 and yield 123-45-****

Currently based on above it yields ***-**-****
```

No idea why. I am using rambda js to simulate.
http://ramdajs.com/docs/#replace

need help to construct the regex for that . Any help is appreciated

Comment: The regex will detect a pattern, it will not result in changing anything. You have to do that wiht a program.

Comment: The regex will replace the last 4 numbers it finds - if you apply it in something like 1234-123-123456 it will match on 1234 as well as 123 as well as 1233456 and for all replace the last 4 numbers.

Comment: Hi Juan and Patrick, I understand, what should i enter in the regex to detect such a pattern. basically what i want to achieve is below   123-45-6789 = 123-45-****  , 123-45-67890 = 123-45-6****

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex matches any digit that doesn't have four other digits immediately following it. Which is the case for every digit in the string 123-45-6789.

If the last four characters of the strings you are working with are always digits you could easily do this without a regex.

But if you want a simple regex, you could search with the following regex and replace with ****.

```
\d{4}$
```

Note that this regex wont match anything if the string doesn't end with four digits. So it would match the first three of the examples below and fail the last three.

```
12-345-6789
123-45-6789
123456789
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9
12-34-56-78-9
123-456-789
```

If you want a regex that will work in all six cases you could use this:

```
\d(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3} *$)
```

Answer (score 0):

R.replace(/\d(?=(?:\D*\d){0,3} *$)/g,'*','123-45-6789');  worked perfectly. Thanks heaps. Kudos to Francis !